# Asp.Net Core adding new files to wwwroot folder change cproj file

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using VS 2017 version 15.2
After project.json migration I received next `.cproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

...

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\*;nlog.config">
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

And everything works fine so far. The problem appears when I added new files into `wwwroot` folder. After that next changes applied in `cproj` file

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="wwwroot\js\my-new-file.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I thought `<None Update="wwwroot\**\*;` configuration added all files in `wwwroot` folder and nothing should be changed after new files appear. And, for example, `Views` folder works in this way. When I added new files into it (`Views` folder) - no changes in `cproj` file.

So, am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know this is a bug or oversight of the .NET Core tooling. You can remove the added lines in the csproj without any problems.

Comment: @YuriyP Have you got any solution for the above issue? I am facing the same scenario, I have added a new file and it shows the entry in csproj, whereas there are no other file entries in csproj. So should I have to commit this or ?

Comment: Nope. For now I just clean up cproj files by myself